# Individual point color in highcharts scatterplot

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Please try the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

and

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
          data: [194.1, 95.6, {y:54.4,color:'#FF0000'}]
        }]
    });
});
```

or run it in [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu9ck/).

HighCharts colors the last bar in red. Now if you change the chart type from 'column' to 'scatter', you will see that HighCharts does not color the last marker but its tooltip.

How can I make HighCharts color a specific point in a scatterplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the "fillColor", instead of (or as well as) the "color":

```
series: [{
  data: [194.1, 95.6, {y:54.4, fillColor:'#FF0000'}]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uu9ck/1/

Comment: You should set `color` to color it's tooltip.

Comment: How would you also set the "hover" state color to match the color/fillColor, instead of the same hover fillColor for all points?

Comment: If anyone is having trouble with that, I did 
`series: [{
  data: [194.1, 95.6, {y:54.4, marker: { fillColor:'#FF0000'}} ]
}]`

for it to work

Comment: Does anybody know how to set a black border to the bubble?

Comment: My series has data like a 2d Array. e.g. 
data : [ 
            [1,2],
            [3,4]
          ],
and i want to add different specific color for each point.
can anyone help me with this.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `fillColor`. `color` works, just like in your example, if you set the **series** type to `scatter` (as opposed to the chart type):

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'scatter',  // <- this
          data: [194.1, 95.6, { y:54.4, color:'#FF0000' }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu9ck/169/).

Comment: Plus, setting the series' `color` attribute instead of its `marker.fillColor` causes the hover halo to match the point's color.